# Add new keyword including an operator to existing language listings

Tags: listings, keywords

I am trying to type set some OPL (Optimization Programming Language) code using the listingspackage. It turns out, that it looks a lot like Java, so I use Java like a "base". However, some keywords, which I need are not present in Java.
I figured out that the keyword `dvar` could be added using

```
\lstset{
  morekeywords={dvar}
}
```

However, I also need to add keywords `int+` and `float+` where the "+" is important as well. If I do

```
\lstset{
      morekeywords={dvar,int+}
    }
```

I do not achieve anything as it seems that the "+" is ignored. From the following

```
\begin{lstlisting}
int anInt = 25; // Declaration of an integer storing the value 25
dvar int+ hej;  // Declaration of a non-negative integer valued decision variable
\end{lstlisting}
```

I get the output

[image]

where it seems the "+" is typeset like an ordinary operator in code and not together with `int` as in `int+`. How can I add a new keyword that includes a ``+''?

---

For completeness, here goes a (minimal) working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\definecolor{napiergreen}{rgb}{0.16, 0.5, 0.0}
\lstset{language=Java,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{napiergreen},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    autogobble=true,    
    morekeywords={dvar,int+}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        int+ anInt = 25; // Declaration of an integer storing the value 25
        dvar int+ hej;  // Declaration of a non-negative integer valued decision variable
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good question, but it would be really helpful if you could put your code fragments into a complete compilable document that people could play with.

Comment: @Alan Munn thank you. I will add a MWE asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell listings to treat `+` as a letter for the purposes of the language definition, by using the `alsoletter` key. As you can see by the examples below, only `+` in the defined keywords is highlighted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java,alsoletter={+},morekeywords={int+,dvar}, keywordstyle={\color{blue}},]
int+ anInt = 25; // Declaration of an integer storing the value 25
dvar int+ hej;  // Declaration of a non-negative integer valued decision variable
dvar+  foo+; 
int + foo;
int+ + foo+;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]